# Spring+Hibernate+Tomcat - BeanInstantiationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am migrating my application from Jboss 5 to Tomcat, I've included Data source configuration in META-INF/context.xml
Also, did the necessary Datasource configurations in the /WEB-INF/web.xml file.

I checked everywhere online and tried almost since a week, but in vain.
What could be the solution for this error

I get the following error: as Datasource cannot be null.

StackTrace

```
     javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:OracleDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:OracleDS].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig.dataSource(UrlConfig.java:60) [urls-core-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig.entityManagerFactoryBean(UrlConfig.java:80) [urls-core-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f9e5a6d.CGLIB$entityManagerFactoryBean$2(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f9e5a6d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4c032d42.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f9e5a6d.entityManagerFactoryBean(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48) [resteasy-spring-3.0.10.Final.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1372) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1336) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1534) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:285) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1142) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1378) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1350) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
2015-07-03_10:40:48.709 UUID: requestURI: [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48) [resteasy-spring-3.0.10.Final.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1372) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1336) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1534) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:285) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1142) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1378) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1350) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.SingleDataSourceLookup.<init>(SingleDataSourceLookup.java:40) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:238) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig.entityManagerFactoryBean(UrlConfig.java:80) ~[urls-core-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f9e5a6d.CGLIB$entityManagerFactoryBean$2(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f9e5a6d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4c032d42.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.di.ps.urls.core.jpa.config.UrlConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f9e5a6d.entityManagerFactoryBean(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you registered your data source under

```
java:/OracleDS
```

and try to look it up under

```
java:OracleDS
```

It might work better, when both names used are the same.

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm getting the following error: "Your persistence provider does not support extracting the JPQL query from a named query thus you can't use Pageable inside your query method. Make sure you have a JpaDialect configured at your EntityManagerFactoryBean as this affects discovering the concrete persistence provider" - What can be the reason for this?

Comment: That is a completely different question. If you can't find a solution, feel free to create a new question.